# failed while trying to reach pointer in struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

my project is to build book structure - and fill it with users parameters.

involving dynamic allocation, arrays and pointers.

my `book` structure has the following:

```
struct BOOK
{
    char* author;
    char** genders;
    int totalGenders;
    char* name;
    int* chapterPages;
    int totalChapters;

}typedef book;
```

when I tried reaching author name, line 1 in structure:

```
struct BOOK
{
    char* author;
```

I failed doing that.. my code in main :

```
int main()
{
    book* b;
    char authorChar[10] = { 0 };
    int authorLen;
    char* authorName;


    // get author name
    puts("please enter the name of the author");
    scanf("%s", &authorChar);
    authorLen = strlen(authorChar);
    printf("%d", authorLen);    //print to see that lentgh is correct.

    authorName = (char*)calloc(authorLen, sizeof(char));
    strcpy(authorName, authorChar);
    puts("\n");
    b->author = authorName;

    printf("%d", b->author);
```

**when i have debugged i got a problem in this line :**

```
b->author = authorName;
```

**ideas please? :)**

Comment: `scanf("%s", &authorChar);`  --> `scanf("%9s", authorChar);`

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the following line

```
  b->author = authorName;
```

at this point, `b` is not allocated memory, i.e., `b` is an uninitialized pointer. It points to some random memory location which is not a *valid* one. Any attempt to access invalid memory invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You can use either of the following approach to resolve the issue:

- allocate memory to `b` dynamically before using it, like `b = malloc(sizeof*b);` and a check for success.
- define `b` as a variable of type `book`, instead of a pointer-to-type.

That said, `int main()` should be `int main(void)` at least, to conform to the standards.

Comment: thank you for your answer ! , my mistake really began when i defined `b` to be a pointer-to-type, without initialize it. (i did it because in the further future, book struct will be just one of - books array...).

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting to do the memory allocation for `b` variable.

```
b = malloc(sizeof(book));
b->author = malloc(sizeof(100000)); // replace value for the size you want
```

Comment: ^^  
Please see the comment under the question on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in C.

Comment: Thank you. There is a looong time I do not code in C. More than 4 years.